# VideoView is unable to play video from Resource

Tags: android, android-layout, video, android-videoview

I have checked other questions, and applied the solution available in them, but still it is not working.

I have placed a video in my `raw` folder.  I am getting the video by using following method

```
String path = "android.resource://" + getPackageName() + "/"+ R.raw.splash_video;

videoView= (VideoView) findViewById(R.id.splash_videoView);

Uri uri= Uri.parse(path);
videoView.setVideoURI(uri);
videoView.start();
```

The video is in `mp4` format, When i run my program, it displays me `Can't play the video` message.

When i debug the code, i found out that, it changes the path value to this:

```
path= android.resource:///2131099757
```

If i change the `path` to Some `URL`, it successfully plays the video.

```
String path= "www.abc.com/someVideo.mp4"
```

Kindly guide me how to play `mp4` video from `raw`

Comment: What is the format of `splash_video` ?

Comment: Are you sure you are getting `package name` in that path ? Are you working with *fragment* or an *activity* ?

Comment: Yes, i checked that again, I am getting package name `com.myapp,app` in the package name, but `res` folder is outside of this package. I am working in activity

Comment: Try with this path `String uriPath = "android.resource://"+getPackageName()+"/raw/myvideo";`.

Comment: Thanks @jaydroider, adding this did the trick.    `String uriPath = "android.resource://"+getPackageName()+"/raw/"+ R.raw.splash_video;`

Comment: I am adding this as answer please upvote and accept so it will be helpful to others :).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> `Try with this URL`.

```
String uriPath = "android.resource://"+getPackageName()+"/raw/myvideo";
```

Where `myvideo` is your `video file name`.